# How to use html and/or css in winform design?

Tags: html, css, winforms

i want to ask you one question.
it can be seemed stupid.
but it is interesting for me.
is there any methods to use html and/or css to design windows application forms.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technology called WPF(Windows Presentation Foundation) in .NET platform,that uses a mark up language called XAML(instead of HTML) for mark up and an styling mechanism like css.but not exactly same as the html and css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resource files to handle your resource in winforms but real answer would be
No there isn't, But its a good idea that's what motivated to develop **WPF**.

To learn it [Go here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)